# How to change the label "Date:" before the date in amsart class?

Tags: languages, amsart, date

I am already using the package babel with the option brazil, which prints, for example, "Proof" as "Demonstração". But the label "Date:", before the date of the document, remains in english. I would like to print it as "Data:" (date in portuguese).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just guessing which datelable exactly it is that you want to change, but adding this to the preamble might do the trick:

```
 \renewcommand{\datename}{\textit{Data}:}
```

Comment: I am surprised though that babel is not catching it, but I have no experience with babel and the amsart class.